# Loop in R, extracting the last line of the output

Tags: r, function, loops

Hei guys,

I've been trying to extract the values from a loop for a while but it seems I just can't find the answer.

To make it simple, here is the code I'm using in R programme:

```
seatsInitial <- function (df,x,y) {
for (i in ModQuota) {
filtered = subset(df, Poll> x)
OnlyPoll <- filtered$Poll
Calculus <- OnlyPoll/i
Calculus2 <- floor(Calculus)
print(Calculus2)
if(sum(Calculus2) == y)
  stop("WE GOT IT")
}
}
```

Then, to get the results:

```
seatsInitial(PartiesE, 5, 33)
```

The loop works properly and I am able to get the results I need. 
The loop stops when the condition is met. However, I would also need to convert the last line of the output (when the loop stops as a result of meeting the condition) into a vector.

Do you have any idea how this could be done?

If I run the loop, I get the following results (showing only the last 5 lines of the output here):

```
[1]  8 14  4  3  5
[1]  8 14  4  3  5
[1]  8 14  4  3  5
[1]  8 14  4  3  5
[1]  7 14  4  3  5
Error in seatsInitial(PartiesEPP, 5, 33) : WE GOT IT
```

I therefore need the last line (7,14,4,3,5) to be converted into a vector.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It already *is* a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include a `return(Calculus2)` at the end and have a `break` inside the if statement.

```
seatsInitial <- function (df,x,y) {
for (i in ModQuota) {
filtered = subset(df, Poll> x)
OnlyPoll <- filtered$Poll
Calculus <- OnlyPoll/i
Calculus2 <- floor(Calculus)
print(Calculus2)
if(sum(Calculus2) == y){
  print("WE GOT IT")
  break
  }
}
return(Calculus2)
}
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks, mickey!